# why maple does not evaluate this limit?

Tags: maple

When i type the following code maple does not evaluate the limit but it clearly exists.

```
> restart; 
> omega := proc (x, y) options operator, arrow; 2*[x, y, 1]/(1+x^2+y^2) end proc;

> phi := proc (x, y) options operator, arrow; Re((lambda*(x+I*y)+a+I*b)/(1-lambda*(a-I*b)*  (x+I*y))), Im((lambda*(x+I*y)+a+I*b)/(1-lambda*(a-I*b)*(x+I*y))) end proc;

> Omega := limit(omega(phi(x/(e^2*(x^2+y^2)), y/(e^2*(x^2+y^2)))), e = 0);
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to map the various operations over a list, as evidenced by your use of `[x,y,1]` in the numerator of the expression in the body of `omega`.

But `*`, `/`, and `limit` will not automatically map over a list.

You can map the `*` and `/` by either using `expand` or the elementwise syntax `*~` and `/~`. For taking the limit I use the `map` command below.

If you didn't intend to map operations over a list then please explain what you intended by `[x,y,1]`.

Note also that the limit as `e->0` can be obtained by Maple if various assumptions are made, or if certain "simplifications" (by `evalc`, which acts as if unknowns are real) are done prior to calling `limit`. By default Maple would otherwise consider the variables other than `e` as being complex.

```
restart; 

omega := (x, y) -> expand( 2*[x, y, 1]/(1+x^2+y^2) ):
#omega := (x, y) -> 2*~[x, y, 1]/~(1+x^2+y^2):

phi := (x, y) -> (Re((lambda*(x+I*y)+a+I*b)/(1-lambda*(a-I*b)*(x+I*y))),
                  Im((lambda*(x+I*y)+a+I*b)/(1-lambda*(a-I*b)*(x+I*y)))):

expr := omega(phi(x/(e^2*(x^2+y^2)), y/(e^2*(x^2+y^2)))):

map(limit,expr,e=0) assuming real;

      [                                / 2    2\]
      [      2 a            2 b      2 \a  + b /]
      [- -----------, - -----------, -----------]
      [   2    2         2    2       2    2    ]
      [  a  + b  + 1    a  + b  + 1  a  + b  + 1]

newexpr := evalc(expr):

map(limit,newexpr,e=0);

      [                                / 2    2\]
      [      2 a            2 b      2 \a  + b /]
      [- -----------, - -----------, -----------]
      [   2    2         2    2       2    2    ]
      [  a  + b  + 1    a  + b  + 1  a  + b  + 1]
```

Let us know, if you had something else in mind.